# How is it possible that POST API working in Postman but not the retrofit?

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2

I'm trying to hit one login API, which also need some headers and body. with the latest version of retrofit, I tried to send headers in both way either with annotation or programatically way, but everytime it says error code 417, exception failed and error body is null, but in postman I'm getting proper reponse.

Comment: unrated to your question, but people have a lot of faith in postman, but it is also just a tool that could make mistakes

Comment: @a_local_nobody this is weird, why is it happening?

Comment: @a_local_nobody can you please post full answer with http login interceptor with add headers also?

Comment: i don't do java anymore, i'm sure someone will give you an answer soon, sorry

Comment: @a_local_nobody O'o my bad luck then :P

Comment: @a_local_nobody it is printing this after adding looging interceptor

    t D/OkHttp: {"nameValuePairs":{"body":{"nameValuePairs":{"customerId":39,"emailId":"aster@lifetrenz.ae","prodId":4,"userPwd":"827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b"}}}}

Comment: Any solution you found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) to compare requests and find out what is wrong.

Comment: How can you give me some more detail?\?

Comment: add `implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0")` in `build.gradle`, then for you `OkHttpClient.Builder` invoke 
`.addNetworkInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        })`
if you done everything right- full http logs will print in logcat

Comment: please add this to your answer, at the moment your answer doesn't add much value :)

Comment: Can you please full answer?

Comment: Make sure I have to add header

Comment: I'll add but as of now, I don't know how to add httpinterceptor with add haders

Comment: you do not need to add any additional headers. 
Using HttpLoggingIntercpter you can just manualy compare what okhttp sending to server vs what it must send

Comment: it is printing this after adding looging interceptor

    t D/OkHttp: {"nameValuePairs":{"body":{"nameValuePairs":{"customerId":39,"emailId":"aster@lifetrenz.ae","prodId":4,"userPwd":"827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b"}}}}

Comment: so, problems is here - request body is wrong.
you cant create DTO
`class RequestBody (val body: Body)
class Body(val customerId: Int, val emailId: String, val prodId: Int,  val userPwd: String)`
then change your
`interface ApiInterface {
        @POST("login/desktop/user")
        Call<Object> getTopRatedMovies(@Body RequestBody body);
    }`

Comment: I tried. I created User class and added seriliazed name and expose annotations and tried. still same error!

Comment: Hi, can you please solve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429082/how-can-i-observe-api-call-based-on-user-submit-button-and-at-same-time-getvalue